# Why does `WebSocket.binaryType` exist?

Tags: javascript, websocket, blob, webapi

`WebSocket` has a `.binaryType` property that determines whether received data is exposed as a `Blob` or an `ArrayBuffer`. Why? `ArrayBuffer` allows you to process the data in a synchronous fashion, but what's the benefit of `Blob`, and why is it the default?

Comment: Blobs can be turned into streams, for one.

Comment: So you can change the binary type,  so your question is why Blob & ArrayBuffers, you might want to look at those to see the pro's & con's of both..  Saying that, questions like this are really not meant for SO,..

Comment: Yes, Blobs can be turned into stream, and ArrayBuffers can be turned into Blobs. The thing about Blobs is that it *forces* you to process it asynchronously, whereas with ArrayBuffers, you can choose either to act synchronously or asynchronously. ArrayBuffers seem strictly more versatile in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) would have to be fully read before it could be used, and all of the data would have to be in memory at the same time. In contrast, a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) can be [read as a stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream), avoiding having to have all the data in memory before you can do anything with it (or at all).

For many purposes, incremental processing of the data from a stream is what you want (such as playing audio or video).

For some purposes, you really need all the data before you can do anything with it, in which case you might use an `ArrayBuffer`.

As for why `Blob` is the default, I'll speculate that it's because it's more flexible. When you need incremental processing, you can get it via the `Blob` (using a stream) without waiting for all the data, and if you need all the data before you start, you can always get an `ArrayBuffer` from the `Blob` via its `arrayBuffer` method.